# The specified procedure could not be found. bson.node

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, mongodb, ntvs

When using visual studio to debg a node project, I get the following error

> Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
>   C:\Source\malum\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\ext\win32\x64\bson.node

Errors on this line

```
var monk = require('monk');
```

This site runs fine when running node and mongodb from the command line.

Comment: If you press F5 (to tell it to keep running), does it work, or does your process actually go down with this error?